# Prevent double byte numbers in form input

Tags: javascript, cjk

Doing this in vanilla javascript. When I input numbers with two-byte character into an html input, I get an error in math we're doing onscreen in javascript, resulting in a “NaN”.

Behind the scenes, I'm taking the input value (a digit) and mulitplying it by a price, to get a total. The total is now NaN with the two byte number. Math is fine with the one byte number.

Is there a way to prevent the input of two-byte characters and letters in javascript?

Two Byte: １２３４５６７
One Byte: 123456

This is all using Japanese to get the two byte numbers.

Comment: ...Language? Library? Framework? Are you using a computer for this, or just talking to people in Japanese?

Comment: Sorry about that, wrote it in haste. Javascript.

Comment: Using a `number` input type prevents non-ASCII digits from being entered, if you cannot use a `number` input type you can register event listeners that prevent the text from being entered if the character code is outside of the range for ASCII digits (48 - 57).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may "prevent" those full-width digits in HTML5 form by type="number", but that might not be the best solution. Some users may not understand why their full-width digits are rejected.

Instead, you can convert them to half-width digits after receiving. It is just subtracting the difference of two character codes.

```
const original = '１２0４４４2８4'
const converted = original.replace(/[０-９]/g, function (s) {
  return String.fromCharCode(s.charCodeAt(0) - 0xFEE0);
})
document.writeln(converted)
```

Output

```
120444284
```